# htaccess - rewrite rule not working when requested URL is a folder on my system

Tags: apache, .htaccess

All requests to my site should be rewritten to `index.php?page=blah`, where blah is the page that's requested (except for css, js, jp(e)g, gif and png files).

This is how my .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:css|js|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The .htaccess is in this directory: `localhost:8080/example/`, so when I go to `localhost:8080/example/abc`, it is (internally) rewritten to `localhost:8080/example/index.php?page=abc`.

However when I go to `localhost:8080/example/res`, I get redirected to `localhost:8080/example/res/?page=res`. I found out that this only happens to directories; when I go to `localhost:8080/example/core`(also a folder on my file system), I get redirected to `localhost:8080/example/core/?page=core` while it should be internally rewritten to `localhost:8080/example/index.php?page=core` and the url visible to the user should stay `localhost:8080/example/core/`

EDIT:

Thanks to @w3dk, who solved the problem stated above. But I found another problem, which may be related to the problem above:

When I go to:
`localhost:8080/example/index/a`, it's internally rewritten to `localhost:8080/example/index.php?page=index.php/a`, while it should be rewritten to `localhost:8080/example/index.php?page=index/a`.

I found out that this happens when `index` is a file, cause when I go to `localhost:8080/example/exampleFile/abc`, it's redirected to `localhost:8080/example/index.php?page=exampleFile.php/abc`, which shouldn't be the case.

The 2 files in my directory are:

- index.php (everything should be directed to this file)
- example.php

Apache seems to ignore the php file extension, cause this also works for exampleFile.txt

Comment: What is the desired result? Do you want to ignore requests for physical directories on your filesystem? Or, internally rewrite the request - the same as for "files", as opposed to triggering an external redirect?

Comment: @w3dk I want to internally rewrite the request the same as for the 'files'. I changed my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably happening because of a conflict with mod_dir. The default behaviour (`DirectorySlash On`) is for mod_dir to automatically "fix" the URL when you request a physical directory *without* a trailing slash. It does this with an external 301 redirect, *before* your rule is processed. Your rule then fires, which modifies the target URL, a `Location` header gets returned to the client and the browser *redirects*.

This won't happen if you include the trailing slash on the original request. eg. `localhost:8080/example/core/`. mod_dir then does not need to "fix" the URL and issue a redirect. Although this may not be desirable for you?

Since you are wanting to internally rewrite *all* directories then the simple fix is to disable this behaviour in `.htaccess`:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, as the earlier 301s by mod_dir will have been cached locally.

Reference (note the security warning):
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash

Comment: Now I got another problem: when I go to `localhost:8080/example/index/a`, apache internally redirects it to `localhost:8080/example/index.php?page=index.php/a`, instead of `localhost:8080/example/index.php?page=index/a`...

Comment: Disable MultiViews: `Options -MultiViews` near the top of your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this 
.htaccess file 
Note: The directory folder1 must be unique in the URL. It won't work for http://domain.com/folder1/folder1.html. The directory folder1 must exist and have content in it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !folder1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/folder1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I still got the same problem.